# timestamp without time zone, date/time field value out of range:

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I get error `{ [error: date/time field value out of range: "1439728672"] ..` .
 I use timestamp without time zone as column and execute query like below use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  I did it success at another database/table I don't know why??

column

```
"CreateDate" timestamp without time zone,
...
```

nodejs postgres

```
 var query = 'INSERT INTO "Article" ("Content","CreateDate") VALUES ($1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING "ArticleId"';
  dbClient.query(query,[content], function(error, result) {
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns timestamp with time zone. You defined `CreateDate` as  timestamp without time zone.

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) :

> CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP deliver values with time zone;
>   LOCALTIME and LOCALTIMESTAMP deliver values without time zone.

Comment: if the app is for global  should I add time zone ?  eg convert all to one type timezone store to database  and then convert it to read ?

Comment: That is your call.... Honestly there are very few cases where time zone actually important (Banking etc...) for most cases it's enough to know the date. Ask your self what are you going to gain by working with time zone? is it an essential to your software?